# Vuejs keyup event trigger with keyCode and condition

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I wanted to bind an event on condition and trigger it only when the user enters a particular key, For example,

1. I want to bind the event when the value of the label equal to tags

   onTagAdd($event, index) : {} }"    v-model="value">

   onTagAdd: function (oEvent, index){
   if(oEvent.key === ";"){
   //some code
   }
   }

It's working as expected.

2. Further, I wanted to trigger the event only when ; ([virtual key code](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-dom/2010JulSep/att-0182/keyCode-spec.html) = 186) pressed, so I have tried below code

   onTagAdd($event, index) : {} }"    v-model="value">

It is not working. I have referred [vue.js documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) But, haven't got any workaround.

How to do this?

Note: I have eliminated this approach as it's giving me an error in IE for $event. still looking for the solution if any which solves the problem and support the browser compatibility.

Comment: In my keyboard, I had to use the keycode 188 instead of 186 to capture the semicolon as in the page that you linked: <input type="text" @keyup.188="...">

Comment: @JaviMollá tried, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try this out and tell me if it worked.

```
<input type="text" v-on:keyup.186="{ (label == 'Tags') ? $event => onTagAdd($event, index) : {} }"    v-model="value">
```

Comment: I have already tried with the different combination of the quote, for above particular combination, below is the error "vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Failed to generate render function:

SyntaxError: Unexpected number in"

Answer (score 0):

maybe the inline style doesn't support keycode in event type(not sure),try this out:

```
<input type="text" v-on:keyup.186="onTagAdd($event,2)"    v-model="value">

methods: {
        onTagAdd(event,index){
            // put your logic codes here
            console.info('==')
            console.info(event)
            console.info(index)
        }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't serve the purpose as I need to bind event only on the specific condition (label == 'Tags') happens.

Comment: you can move your condition inside the method , is there any restriction? just like this : `if (this.label === 'Tags') .... else ...`

Comment: if it's the `label` field dynamic you can simply pass it as a param to the method and do your logic inside

Comment: I have eliminated this approach as it's giving me an error in IE for $event. still looking for the solution if any which solves the problem and support the browser compatibility. (Note added in Que.)

Answer (score 0):

This page was helpful for me in Vue3: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/keycode-modifiers.html

**3.x Syntax#**

Since KeyboardEvent.keyCode has been deprecated, it no longer makes sense for Vue 3 to continue supporting this as well. As a result, it is now recommended to use the kebab-case name for any key you want to use as a modifier.

```html
<!-- Vue 3 Key Modifier on v-on -->
<input v-on:keyup.page-down="nextPage">

<!-- Matches both q and Q -->
<input v-on:keypress.q="quit">
```

As a result, this means that config.keyCodes is now also deprecated and will no longer be supported.

TLDR: in Vue 3 keycodes appear to be deprecated in favour of using kebab case.

For example, `@keyup.186` would be `@keyup.;`